# Oxidation of ethanol upon heating in a test tube

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, redox

> The diagram shows an experimental set-up which can be used in several different experiments.
>
> [image: experimental set-up]
>
> Which processes could be demonstrate by using the above apparatus?
>
> **1**. Oxidation of ethanol (liquid X)
> **2**. Dehydration of ethanol (liquid X)
> **3**. Cracking of paraffin (liquid X)

The answer is **2** and **3**. I understand that for **2**, ethene is produced which is a gas and for **3**, cracking of paraffin will produce short-chained hydrocarbons which have low boiling points.

However, I expected **1** to be an answer as well because oxidation of ethanol will produce ethanal which has a boiling point of 21 °C. So shouldn't **1** be an answer as well?

Comment: An oxidant is needed if you want to oxidize ethanol into ethanal. And there is no oxidant in this picture.

Comment: @Maurice wouldn't you need a catalyst for the dehydration of ethanol as well (e.g. concentrated sulfuric acid)?

Comment: Silica is an acidic surface

Comment: @Waylander Oh, I see... and alumina also acts as a catalyst for the dehydration of alcohols. My bad for assuming that oxidants were added. Thank you